# Problem with returning generic type from function

Tags: generics, rust, downcast, trait-objects

I have a function that searches through a list of trait objects and attempts to find one whose implementor is of a specific type, however the compiler doesent accept the return type.

```
pub struct GameObject{
    pub modules: Vec<Box<dyn ModuleTrait>>, 
}

impl GameObject {
   pub fn find_module_of_type<T: ModuleTrait>(&self) -> Result<T> {  
        //iterate through the modules
        self.modules
            .iter()
            .for_each(|m| {
                let module = m.as_any().downcast_ref::<T>();

                //see if mosule is of the correct type 
                if match module {
                    Some(T) => true,
                    None => false,
                } {
                    return Ok(module); //this is where the error happens
                }
            });
            
        Err(anyhow!("The specified module could not be found"))
    }
}

pub trait ModuleTrait {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

pub struct Transform{
    pub value: i32
}

impl ModuleTrait for Transform {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}
```

this gives the error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\scene\game_object.rs:42:28
   |
42 |                     return Ok(module);
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^ expected `()`, found `Result<Option<&T>, _>`
   |
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                   found enum `std::result::Result<Option<&T>, _>`
note: return type inferred to be `()` here
  --> src\scene\game_object.rs:42:28
   |
42 |                     return Ok(module);
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`
```

The error message confuses me even more as it first tells me the unit return type is inferred but at the same time it isnt a unit type.

I tried to unwrap the module but that gave roughly the same error message

Comment: The `return` statement returns from the closure you pass to `for_each()`, not from `find_module_of_type()`. You should almost always use a `for` loop instead of `for_each()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Finding an object already has a method on `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) since you want to change the type as well I used [`find_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find_map) here instead:

```rust
impl GameObject {
    pub fn find_module_of_type<T: ModuleTrait + 'static>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        self.modules
            .iter()
            .find_map(|m| m.as_any().downcast_ref::<T>())  
    }
}
```

Modifications made:

- `for_each` → `find_map` that's what you want to do after all.
- `Result` → `Option` If your only error is "object matching criteria not found" that's exactly what `Option` is for. If you want to disambiguate errors further up the call chain you can always turn that `Option` into a `Result` with [`Option::ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or) there.
- Since you only get a refernce and don't know how to `Copy` or `Clone` a `T` you can't really return a value, only a reference so `Option<T>` → `Option<&T>`
- Added a bound of `T: 'static` since that's a requirement to be able to `downcast` to it (See the bound on [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html)).